Lists webpart without scroll
I'm using a list webpart to display a 'Gallery view' list on my SharePoint page. Even with the size option set to 'Autosize - fit to number of items' the webpart is cutting off my last row and showing a vertical scrollbar. Is there a way of increasing the height of the webpart to show all items? It seems to max out around 1840px.
